# THREEjs - using an animated gif as a displacement map - shaders

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I've been working off this example http://meetar.github.io/threejs-shader-demos/llama.html that uses an animated gif as a displacement map. However, it uses THREE.js r58 and I'm using THREE.js r85 and the following code from the example doesn't work for me

```
dispTexture = new THREE.Texture(llamacanvas);

var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];
uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( shader.uniforms );

uniforms[ "enableDisplacement" ] = { type: 'i', value: 1 };
uniforms[ "tDisplacement" ] = { type: 't', value: dispTexture };
uniforms[ "uDisplacementScale" ] = { type: 'f', value: 35 };

uniforms[ "enableDiffuse" ] = { type: 'i', value: 1 };
uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = dispTexture;

uniforms[ "tNormal" ] = { type: 't', value: new 
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'flat.png' )};
```

at first `var shader = THREE.ShaderLib[ "normalmap" ];` was giving me trouble - error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uniforms' of undefined

so I replaced `normalmap` with `normal`, which fixes that error,
 but then  `uniforms["tDiffuse"].value = dispTexture` gives me an error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined

This is when I discovered the huge difference in THREE.js builds. I was wondering if someone can help me understand how this can be implemented in more recent versions of THREE.js

It has something to do with `geometry.computeTangents();` which was still part of r58, but has been removed.

Thanks!

update:
I'm continuing to work on this and I replaced `tDiffuse` with `diffuse` and every time the animation loop updates I get this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined
```

The console points me to a spot in three.min.js, not in the example code I am using:

```
      if (c.morphNormals)
        for (m = c.numSupportedMorphNormals = 0; m < J.maxMorphNormals; m++)
          0 <= l["morphNormal" + m] && c.numSupportedMorphNormals++;
      l = h.__webglShader.uniforms;
      if (!c.isShaderMaterial && !c.isRawShaderMaterial || !0 === c.clipping)
        h.numClippingPlanes = Oa.numPlanes,
        h.numIntersection = Oa.numIntersection,
        l.clippingPlanes = Oa.uniform;
      h.fog = b;
      h.lightsHash = da.hash;
      c.lights && (l.ambientLightColor.value = da.ambient,
      l.directionalLights.value = da.directional,
      l.spotLights.value = da.spot,
      l.rectAreaLights.value = da.rectArea,
      l.pointLights.value = da.point,
      l.hemisphereLights.value = da.hemi,
      l.directionalShadowMap.value = da.directionalShadowMap,
      l.directionalShadowMatrix.value = da.directionalShadowMatrix,
      l.spotShadowMap.value = da.spotShadowMap,
      l.spotShadowMatrix.value = da.spotShadowMatrix,
      l.pointShadowMap.value = da.pointShadowMap,
      l.pointShadowMatrix.value = da.pointShadowMatrix);
      m = h.program.getUniforms();
      l = db.seqWithValue(m.seq, l);
      h.uniformsList = l
    }
    c.needsUpdate = !1
  }
```

Specifically, the program stops at

```
c.lights && (l.ambientLightColor.value = da.ambient,
```

having a problem with `da.ambient`. I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Figured this out. Much less complicated than I thought it would be.

In r85 I don't need to worry about explicitly setting up the uniforms at all. All I had to do was import the gif, create the material then add the gifCanvas:

      var supGif = new SuperGif({ gif: document.getElementById('gif1') } );
      supGif.load();
      var gifCanvas = supGif.get_canvas();material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
        material.displacementMap = new THREE.Texture( gifCanvas );

Answer (score 0):

Much less complicated than I thought.

In r85 no need to explicitly set up the uniforms. Only had to import the gif, create the material then add the gifCanvas as a displacementMap:

```
var supGif = new SuperGif({ gif: document.getElementById('gif1') } );
supGif.load();
var gifCanvas = supGif.get_canvas();

                          .      .      .

material = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial();
material.map = new THREE.Texture( gifCanvas );
material.displacementMap = material.map;
```

Then in the `animate()` function:

```
material.displacementScale = 200;
material.map.needsUpdate = true;
material.displacementMap.needsUpdate = true;
```

I looked at CanvasTexture and ShaderMaterial for awhile but not necessary for this.