# Is there possibility to use GIF animation in threejs?

Tags: three.js

I'm really confused about the use of GIF animations in threejs. There are no examples on google, I can't find any statement about gifs, are they supported or no?

I can not believe that threejs has a problem with GIF animations. Is it really hard to implement?

I only want to add to my space rocket prepared to fire from my graphic designer.

Any clues? Please I'm run out of the ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't directly use an animated `GIF` in `three.js` as a texture. You have the following options:

- Convert the `GIF` to a video (e.g. `MP4`) and then use [THREE.VideoTexture](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/textures/VideoTexture).
- Create a sprite sheet which contains all frames of the animation and use it as an ordinary `THREE.Texture`. The animation is done by offsetting the respective texture coordinates per frame.
- Try to use `SuperGif` like describe in another [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452433/5250847).

Related discussion at the `three.js` forum: [GIF as animated texture?](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/gif-as-animated-texture/1097)

`three.js R103`